# Passing Memory in task : Verilog

Tags: verilog

I am trying to do something like this:

```
module test;

reg [1:0] c [1:0];
reg [1:0] a1 [1:0];

 task mem_a;
 output reg [1:0] a [1:0];
 begin
  a[0]=0;
  a[1]=1;
  a[2]=2;
  a[3]=3;
 end
endtask

task mem_b;
 input reg [1:0] a2 [1:0];
 output reg [1:0] b [1:0];
 begin
  b=a2; // or some other manupulation 
 end
endtask

initial
begin
 mem_a (a1);
 mem_b (a1,c);
end

endmodule
```

When I compile this, I am getting errors as :

1. Illegal reference to memory "b"
2. Illegal LHS of assignment.
3. Illegal reference to memory "a2"
4. Illegal task output argument.
5. Illegal reference to memory "a1".

So  I want to understand how to pass 2-D arrays in tasks.

P.S: I have not used tasks before.

Comment: Two dimensional arrays are not supported in Verilog. SystemVerilog supports them as ports and arguments to tasks.

Comment: One immediate mistake is declaring inputs/outputs as `output reg [1:0] b [1:0]`. In verilog task, the name of variable is expected after the argument direction. So do it as `output [1:0] b [1:0]` without the `reg` keyword. This is not the main issue here, just a side comment. :)

Comment: Is any workaround possible?. Also I want to understand why **reg or wire** is not expected after **inputs/outputs** ?

Comment: Verilog either has `reg` or `wire` as datatype, only two in the main perspective. But, wire is driven by **continuous assignments** `assign` statements only, so `wire` is never expected. As a result, **output** arguments are implicitly of `reg` type. As far as **input** argument is concerned, it is simply a variable, whose value must be read. As a result, it can be `reg` or `wire`. Systemverilog having many datatypes requires **explicit** declaration of datatypes in input/output arguments. Are you looking for a verilog task/function or systemverilog task/function?

Comment: Oh got it. I am looking only for verilog task/function.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible in Verilog.  You're probably just going to have to 'unroll' the tasks inline.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution is to flatten the arrays. For instance:

```
module test;

// reg [1:0] c1 [1:0] ends up as:
reg [2*2-1:0] c;
reg [2*2-1:0] a1;

task mem_a;
output reg [2*2-1:0] a;
begin
  a[2*0+:2]=2'd0;
  a[2*1+:2]=2'd1;
  //a[2]=2; // This was out of bounds
  //a[3]=3; // So was this
end
endtask

task mem_b;
input  reg [2*2-1:0] a2;
output reg [2*2-1:0] b;
begin
  b=a2; // or some other manipulation 
end
endtask

initial
begin
  mem_a (a1);
  mem_b (a1,c);
end

endmodule
```